# How can I forecast a time series using Cart models?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cart, rpart

I'm using the `rpart` library to try forecasting the electricity consumption from Australia (example from the book Introductory Time Series with R):

```
 CBE : 
choc    beer    elec
1451    96.3    1497
....
All the data is separate in months from 1958 til 1970

library(rpart)
www <- "http://staff.elena.aut.ac.nz/Paul-Cowpertwait/ts/cbe.dat"
CBE <- read.table(www, header = T)
Elec.ts <- ts(CBE[, 3], start = 1958, freq = 12)

plot(cbind(Elec.ts))


fit <- rpart(elec~elec, method="anova", data=CBE)
pre <- predict(fit)

Elec.predict <- ts(pre[], start = 1958, freq = 12)
plot(cbind(Elec.ts,Elec.predict ))
```

It's really simple, the R program **does not run**, if I try to create a model using the **elec data it self**.

Am I using it wrong?
How Can I use this library properly ?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622951/how-forecast-a-time-series-with-cart-models

Comment: @Pascal I'm trying to get some help. can you help me?

Comment: `Elec` is highlighted - is it some sort of a keyword in R?

also - you use `Elec` to fetch the `CBE` data. why do you then plug the `CBE` data to the regression, not the `Elec` data?

Comment: @metjush sorry I will make more clear. I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an analog to the autoregressive models, you need to regress elec against lagged elec.

```
nLag <- 6 # regression in the 6 last lags 
CBE <- setDT(CBE)[, paste0('elec', 1:nLag) := shift(elec, 1:nLag)][] # making the lags as inputs 
fit <- rpart(elec~., method="anova", data=CBE)
```

Comment: Hey is that work ? Have you tried ?

Comment: This looks reasonable - give it a try Alvaro. I think the problem was the `elec~elec` part. It was in fact regressing the variable in time `t` on itself (also in time `t`).